# Python-QTableWidget: How to catch signal when sorting in header is clicked

Tags: python, sorting, pyqt4, signals-slots, qtablewidget

While filling tableWidget with some text I've used `self.ui.tableWidget.resizeRowToContents` for every row.
After that and: `self.ui.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(1)` ,sorting is working as expected but rows are not resize to content anymore, in fact they preserve previous height.

```
name                              name v                 name v
---------                         ---------              ---------
text2                             text1line1             text1line1
---------  after sort is clicked: ---------   expected:  text1line2
text1line1                                               text1line3
text1line2                        text2                  ---------
text1line3                                               text2
---------                         ---------              ---------
```

My idea is to catch signal when sorting in header is clicked, and go again with `self.ui.tableWidget.resizeRowToContents`  through all rows.
**How to catch that signal?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to call `resizeRowToContents` for every row that is added.

Instead, after the table is filled, call the [`resizeRowsToContents`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtableview.html#resizeRowsToContents) slot, which will resize all the rows at once.

You can then connect the same slot to the [`sortIndicatorChanged`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qheaderview.html#sortIndicatorChanged) signal, so that the rows are resized whenever the columns are sorted:

```
# ... fill table, then:
self.ui.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
self.ui.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorChanged.connect(
    self.ui.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are signals on the header objects that you could connect to: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qheaderview.html

```
header = self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
header.sortIndicatorChanged.connect(self.fixRowSizes)
```

You can also try setting the resize mode for your rows as you populate:

```
# grab the header object
row_header = self.ui.tableWidget.verticalHeader()

# populate some data
self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(100)
self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(100)
for row in range(100):
    for col in range(100):
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, col, QTableWidgetItem(str(row * col)))

    # mark each row to automatically resize to contents
    row_header.setResizeMode(row, QHeaderView.ResizeToContens)
```

The negative of this approach is that the user control over the size is disabled when set to ResizeToContents.  As long as your user doesn't ever intend/need to resize manually - this is a good way to go about it.